# How to customize the userstore provider for identity server and also make my AccountController work together with IdentityServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman, identityserver4

I'am working on  a new `Asp.net core (.Net 5)` application and i need to implement an authentication server using `IdentityServer` as token provider . The customer asked us to do not use `Asp.net core Identity` and we have to use `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` and `ProfileService` .
I made everything work and i am getting the access_token based on the `UserName` and the `Password` (from the Url/Connect/token) but there is a  missing part : the Account controller .

So i am asking how to make the `Identityserver` and my `AccountController` works together.
When the login action invoked and the authentication succeeded i want to invoke the `IdentityServer` mechanisme.
So guys if anyone has a hint or anything that would be appreciated ,and thanks in advance.

Comment: What does AccountController do? If you are already using `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator ` and `ProfileService ` to complete the Authentication and generate a token, so where does AccountController come into play?

Comment: i want to perform the logout , is it possible to do it with ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator   ?

Answer (score 0):

For a new OpenID Connect project today, you should only consider to use the Authorization Code flow or the Clients credentials flow. All the other flows has been deprecated due to various security issues (Search for OAuth 2.1)

I understand why they don't want to use ASP.NET Identity, but a compromise canbe to still use the ASP.NET Identity database scheme and its existing integration with IdentityServer. By using the schema used by ASP.NET Identiy, you can then use one of the many existing user management solutions that exists out there, just like this picture shows:

[image]

Ie, use the ASP.NET Identity database tables and the included support for that in IdentityServer, but use something else to actually manage the content in the database table.